# Gradle 3.0 "compile" to "implementation" migration doesn't work for fileTree

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to remove all my lint warnings but I'm stuck with one of the `compile` to `implementation` migrations.

If I change this:

```
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

to this:

```
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

then the app won't build and I get the following error:

> Error:Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: ... unresolved supertypes: veg.mediaplayer.sdk.MediaPlayer.MediaPlayerCallback

Is this a bug or am I supposed to do something different for fileTree? I couldn't find any explanations looking at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html.

I've changed all the other lines in all gradle files from `compile` to `implementation` and they all work fine.

**Edit**: I should also note that this particular module does have a jar in the lib folder. For modules with no jars it works.

**Edit 2:** I've noticed that actually it doesn't always happen if there is a jar. I have another module with a jar (that I created) and it works fine. Something must be wrong with the mediaplayersdk.jar.

Given that it's only complaining about the callback that is implemented from a file in the jar, I suppose that is where it's getting stuck.

I also tried with Android Studio 3.1.0-beta1 and gradle 4.4 but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you please post the full error log?

Comment: @Debdeep I added the end of the error which tells you about the jar but left out the exact class name in the middle since it's not relevant.

Comment: so it seems that it doesn't work when you implement a callback from the jar.

Comment: Just an update to this question. As of 6.0.1, the above syntax now works.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok I feel like an idiot now. All I had to do was read the documentation more carefully and I would have seen that `api` is the equivalent of `compile` and is supported going forward.

Using `api` works!

i.e. `api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: this way you are explaining api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')!

Answer (score 0):

From the Gradle migration doc

> When your module configures an implementation dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module does not want to leak the dependency to other modules at compile time.

Also

> Previously, library modules would handle dependencies on local JARs in a non- standard way and would package them inside their AAR. Even in a multi-project build, consumers of the AAR would see these JAR files through the packaged version.

And

> Library modules no longer process local JARs. This is to speed up incremental builds that are caused by changes to a library module's code.

So If you're keeping any local jars, you may want to use `compile` instead. But note that `compile` and the older ones will be removed in the upcoming significant release of Android plugin.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the whole point of the question is how do I remove the "compile"? Like you said, compile will be removed in the future (and thus it's a lint warning). I still need the jar as it's fundamental to the app.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
```

This worked for me